# Remove empty tuples from Seq[(String,Any)] in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have Seq[(String, Any)]

```
(Foo,1 ) 
(bar,2)
(baz,)
```

and I want to filter out baz as it does not have a value  how can I check and remove  (baz,) only

Comment: What is the type of that empty tuple? what does it mean for a tuple to be "empty"?

Comment: What do you mean, "Doesn't have any value?" It must be something (maybe empty string)?

Comment: Let’s say it has null or white space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove tuples whose second part contains `null` or a whitespace-only string:

```
someList.filter {
  case (_, s: String) => s.trim.nonEmpty
  case (_, x) => x != null
}
```

I think this is pretty readable, but, if performance is an issue, you might replace `s.trim.nonEmpty` with `s.exists(!Character.isWhitespace(_))`.

Comment: `s.trim` could inspect and construct very long string, even if it is clear after the first character that the string is not whitespace-only.

Comment: Just in case you find it interesting: a simple micro-benchmark shows two things: 1) On non-contrived input, your idiomatic solution seems even a tiny bit faster than my `instanceOf`-proposal (which I find a bit surprising); 2) If the input contains non-empty strings such that `s.trim != s`, then your solution needs more time, because it keeps allocating memory for trimmed strings, instead of looking for non-whitespace symbols in-place; By the way: `s.exists(_ != ' ')` won't catch `\t` and all the other weird whitespace-characters.

Comment: @Andrey I fixed the \t issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
seq.filterNot { case (_, y) => (
    y.isInstanceOf[String] && 
    y.asInstanceOf[String].forall(_.isWhitespace)
  ) || y == null
}
```

---

After testing my own and @BrianMcCutchon's intermediate solution proposals in a little micro-benchmark, I came to the conclusion that

```
seq.filterNot { 
  case (_, s: String) => s.forall(_.isWhitespace)
  case (_, n) => n == null
}
```

is both one of the shortest, and also one of the fastest solutions. This is essentially @BrianMcCutchon's pattern matching combined with `isWhitespace`, and transformed through De-Morgan's Laws (avoids inner negation around `isWhitespace`, but works with `forall` and `filterNot` instead).

*That's kind-of a merge between the two answers, I'm not sure how to deal with that? Should I move it into a separate community wiki answer? (upvoted the other answer for now, to rebalance a little bit)*

Comment: I'm generally suspicious of using a cast. In this case, pattern matching gets the job done fine and in a type-safe manner.

Comment: I am generally suspicious of `Any`. I usually stop caring about type-safety too much if I see a `(String, Any)` out in the wild, not in the code that is doing some deserialization. I'm currently more worried about the fact that `matches` keeps re-compiling the regex for every tuple, it's wasteful.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I don't know why I'm not into pattern matching today, just wanted to write something simple and low-level, without too much unpredictable desugaring. I understand that it's not the most idiomatic way to write it, but it might be a tiny bit more performant.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I've decided to add a short solution with pattern matching after all. I'm not sure what to do with that, because I clearly borrowed the two-case pattern matching from you. Should I move the "combined" answer into a separate community wiki answer?